# Entity Framework separate DbContext per c(r)ud operation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I encountered some strange issue using entity framework and I am not sure what's the moral.

Should I use a separate context object for every create, update and delete operation?

I have an entity, that has a unique constraint. I receive values from a different thread and want to store them in an entity and persist them to the database. If I am using one DbContext and adding an entity fails because of unique constraint violation, all following attempts to store an valid entity will fail, too. This is because the invalid entity is still in the DbContext's set.

The problem reduces to this, I think:

```
/* 
 * m_context is a memeber variable of the class and created once
 * new MyEntity("unique") => creates new entity and sets the unique attribute to the passed value
 * the entity's key is set automatically
 */
//works fine
try { m_context.MyEntities.Add(new MyEntity("unique"); m_context.SaveChanges() } catch{} 
//fails because of unique constraint violation => this is okay
try { m_context.MyEntities.Add(new MyEntity("unique"); m_context.SaveChanges() } catch{} 
//fails, too => not okay and not expected
try { m_context.MyEntities.Add(new MyEntity("unique2"); m_context.SaveChanges() } catch{}
```

Exceptions are System.Data.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException (an error occurred while updating the entries) -> System.Data.UpdateException (an error occurred while updating the entries) -> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (constraint failed column ... is not unique)

=> In the scenario above twice, with separate context (see below), once, only.

I think the problem will occur with every database provider and is not related to SQLite.

So there are at least two solutions:

1. Remove the second entity manually from the DbSet in MyContext
2. Use a seperate context for each create operation

I tend to use the second. This is because I saw a lot of using statements in tutorials/code.
I never understood the reason for this massive recreation of the same object, but this might be a (the) reason. Is this true, or am I completely wrong.

This problem also exists for update and delete operations. And another reasons for failure might be a foreign key violation.

So what's the best practice here? Separate context object per operation? But is the object really that light-weight? And should I apply the "one context per operation" to read operations, too?

As already mentioned, the fix is obvious, but the moral is not totally clear to me, and I am interested in what's the best practice here. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the problem in using the same context. What happens if you execute only the 3rd statement? What is the error message, could you please post it? Are you sure you don't have that value already in the database?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply! Yes, I am 100% sure about the issue, I verified it again a minute ago. I set up a test that empties the database in advance. Exceptions are System.Data.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException (error while updating entries) -> System.Data.UpdateException (error while updating entries) -> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (constraint failed column ... is not unique) In the scenario above twice, with separate context, once, only.

Comment: Just to confirm.... Sometimes we lose a lot of time with silly mistakes :) It would help if you updated your post with the error message

Comment: You have the error 2 times because you still have the 2nd object attached to the context, it's not the 3rd statement that is failing.

Comment: Well, yes: I know that the second entity is still attached when the third statement is executed and that this is the reason for failure. That's exactly my problem: How to detach the second one? This can either be done using a separate context or remove it manually. I mentioned this in the question, already. The problem is not to fix the issue but HOW to fix it => what is best practice here? Thanks!